# How to position green div under the red one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, debugging

**Below is the demo code which fully represent the actual code**

I've placed some content on the red `div` which I want users to see when the page loads. The problem is that I'm using ***scrollmagic.js*** animations on this page. Everything was working perfect but when I tried to use ***smoothscroll***, The `.setPin` fuctions of scrollmagic stopped working. The animations are still working but the red `div` is being scrolled with the other divs. I want the red `div` to stay on it's place until the animation don't finish. The ***smoothscroll*** pushes the red `div` along the other divs before the animation completes.

Can you please help me placing green and blue `div` under the red one while the red div's position is fixed and stays responsive so that everything will work on all screen sizes?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test Code</title>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>

</head>


<style>
  .viewport {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
  }
  
  .scroll-container {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 10;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
  }
  
  .div1 {
    width: 70%;
    height: 70vh;
    border: 5px solid red;
    position: fixed;
    transform: translateX(20%);
  }
  
  .div2 {
    width: 70%;
    height: 70vh;
    border: 5px solid green;
    transform: translateX(20%);
  }
  
  .div3 {
    width: 70%;
    height: 70vh;
    border: 5px solid blue;
    transform: translateX(20%);
  }
</style>



<body>

  <div class="div1"></div>

  <div class="viewport">
    <div id="scroll-container">

      <div class="div2"></div>
      <div class="div3"></div>


    </div>
  </div>

</body>

<script>
  var html = document.documentElement;
  var body = document.body;

  var scroller = {
    target: document.querySelector("#scroll-container"),
    ease: 0.05, // <= scroll speed
    endY: 0,
    y: 0,
    resizeRequest: 1,
    scrollRequest: 0,
  };

  var requestId = null;

  TweenLite.set(scroller.target, {
    rotation: 0.01,
    force3D: true
  });

  window.addEventListener("load", onLoad);

  function onLoad() {
    updateScroller();
    window.focus();
    window.addEventListener("resize", onResize);
    document.addEventListener("scroll", onScroll);
  }

  function updateScroller() {

    var resized = scroller.resizeRequest > 0;

    if (resized) {
      var height = scroller.target.clientHeight;
      body.style.height = height + "px";
      scroller.resizeRequest = 0;
    }

    var scrollY = window.pageYOffset || html.scrollTop || body.scrollTop || 0;

    scroller.endY = scrollY;
    scroller.y += (scrollY - scroller.y) * scroller.ease;

    if (Math.abs(scrollY - scroller.y) < 0.05 || resized) {
      scroller.y = scrollY;
      scroller.scrollRequest = 0;
    }

    TweenLite.set(scroller.target, {
      y: -scroller.y
    });

    requestId = scroller.scrollRequest > 0 ? requestAnimationFrame(updateScroller) : null;
  }

  function onScroll() {
    scroller.scrollRequest++;
    if (!requestId) {
      requestId = requestAnimationFrame(updateScroller);
    }
  }

  function onResize() {
    scroller.resizeRequest++;
    if (!requestId) {
      requestId = requestAnimationFrame(updateScroller);
    }
  }
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: I must be missing something - in your snippet (well done for providing a snippet btw)  your red box stays where it is when the "page" (snippet output) is scrolled - the other boxes "scroll" in a really annoying, motion-sickness-inducing manner, but I guess that's was your intent.

Comment: red div have position fixed property on it. it will stay at same place always. may be you looking for sticky ?

Comment: @freedomn-m Actually I want the red `div` to be on it's place and all other divs e.g green and blue under the red one.

Comment: Perhaps you might like to clarify this in your question then, because it currently very clearly asks about the red div moving: *"the animations are still working but the red div is **being scrolled with the other divs**. I want the red div **to stay on it's place** until the animation don't finish. The smoothscroll pushes the red div **along the other divs** before the animation completes."* [sic]

Answer (score 1):

Use `z-index` to place the red div above the other divs:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test Code</title>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>

</head>


<style>
  .viewport {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
  }
  
  .scroll-container {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 10;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
  }
  
  .div1 {
    width: 70%;
    height: 70vh;
    border: 5px solid red;
    position: fixed;
    transform: translateX(20%);
    z-index: 10;
  }
  
  .div2 {
    width: 70%;
    height: 70vh;
    border: 5px solid green;
    transform: translateX(20%);
  }
  
  .div3 {
    width: 70%;
    height: 70vh;
    border: 5px solid blue;
    transform: translateX(20%);
  }
</style>



<body>

  <div class="div1"></div>

  <div class="viewport">
    <div id="scroll-container">

      <div class="div2"></div>
      <div class="div3"></div>


    </div>
  </div>

</body>

<script>
  var html = document.documentElement;
  var body = document.body;

  var scroller = {
    target: document.querySelector("#scroll-container"),
    ease: 0.05, // <= scroll speed
    endY: 0,
    y: 0,
    resizeRequest: 1,
    scrollRequest: 0,
  };

  var requestId = null;

  TweenLite.set(scroller.target, {
    rotation: 0.01,
    force3D: true
  });

  window.addEventListener("load", onLoad);

  function onLoad() {
    updateScroller();
    window.focus();
    window.addEventListener("resize", onResize);
    document.addEventListener("scroll", onScroll);
  }

  function updateScroller() {

    var resized = scroller.resizeRequest > 0;

    if (resized) {
      var height = scroller.target.clientHeight;
      body.style.height = height + "px";
      scroller.resizeRequest = 0;
    }

    var scrollY = window.pageYOffset || html.scrollTop || body.scrollTop || 0;

    scroller.endY = scrollY;
    scroller.y += (scrollY - scroller.y) * scroller.ease;

    if (Math.abs(scrollY - scroller.y) < 0.05 || resized) {
      scroller.y = scrollY;
      scroller.scrollRequest = 0;
    }

    TweenLite.set(scroller.target, {
      y: -scroller.y
    });

    requestId = scroller.scrollRequest > 0 ? requestAnimationFrame(updateScroller) : null;
  }

  function onScroll() {
    scroller.scrollRequest++;
    if (!requestId) {
      requestId = requestAnimationFrame(updateScroller);
    }
  }

  function onResize() {
    scroller.resizeRequest++;
    if (!requestId) {
      requestId = requestAnimationFrame(updateScroller);
    }
  }
</script>

</html>
```